# How to select a random result for each distinct item in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following tables

- Questions
- Answers
- Users
- Votes

Sample table set would be like so
Question Table:

```
question_id  | question
1            | Question #1
2            | Question #2
3            | Question #3
4            | Question #4
5            | Question #5
```

Answers Table:

```
answer_id      | answer      | user_id      | question_id
1              | Answer #1   | 2            | 1
2              | Answer #2   | 2            | 2
3              | Answer #3   | 3            | 2
4              | Answer #4   | 1            | 3
5              | Answer #6   | 1            | 2
6              | Answer #7   | 2            | 5
7              | Answer #8   | 1            | 5
8              | Answer #9   | 3            | 1
9              | Answer #10  | 2            | 5
```

User Table:

```
user_id   | name 
1         | user #1
2         | user #2
3         | user #3
```

Votes Table:

```
vote_id   | vote_type   | user_id  | answer_id
1         | 1           | 1        | 1
2         | 0           | 3        | 1
3         | 0           | 3        | 8
4         | 1           | 2        | 3
5         | 1           | 2        | 4
6         | 0           | 1        | 4
7         | 1           | 3        | 3
8         | 0           | 1        | 5
9         | 1           | 1        | 2
```

I need help writing a query that will allow me to display each item once (even those without an answer) with a random answer and the total number of votes it has received.

Example Result:

```
[Question 1 | Answer_id = 8   | user_id = 3   | total votes: 1  ]
[Question 2 | Answer_id = 3   | user_id = 3   | total votes: 2  ]
[Question 3 | Answer_id = 4   | user_id = 1   | total votes: 2  ]
[Question 4 | Answer_id = n/a | user_id = n/a | total votes: n/a]
[Question 5 | Answer_id = 10  | user_id = 2   | total votes: 0  ]
```

And if I was to refresh the query it would output the same questions with random answers (if a different answer is available).

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between the `user_id` in the `answers` table and the `user_id` in the `votes` table?

Comment: @PoeHaH i've tried a number of ways to do this, but nothing that worked, mainly using distinct as a way to isolate the question (which worked) but I was unable to get the answers to be random and could not find an answer online that combined the two.  I am still learning all the ins and outs of MySQL and therefore I do not have any experience with nested queries. Also I will include what I have tried to the question next time.  thanks.

Comment: @ZaneBien The difference between the two is that one marks who answered the question, and the other marks who voted on the answer.  They are better marked on the actual database.  Sorry for the confusion. Also thank you very much for your answer below.  I am trying to incorporate it to my database but keep getting an error, I will play around with it and hopefully get it to work.

Comment: @MichaelCheung, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ZaneBien Figured it out, there were hidden charachters mucking up the query.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT a.question, a.answer_id, a.user_id, a.totalvotes
FROM
(
    SELECT a.question, b.answer_id, c.user_id, COUNT(d.vote_id) AS totalvotes
    FROM questions a
    LEFT JOIN answers b ON a.question_id = b.question_id
    LEFT JOIN users c ON b.user_id = c.user_id
    LEFT JOIN votes d ON b.answer_id = d.answer_id
    GROUP BY a.question, b.answer_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
) a
GROUP BY a.question
```

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faab9/4/0)

^ You can keep hitting the "Run SQL" button and different answers will appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND()` in your query.

Comment: Notice that this can be slow if your table is large. If you `ORDER BY RAND()` and also `LIMIT 1`, MySQL has to read and sort your _whole_ table, only to return the first row. (This is opposed to, for instance, if you ordered by a field that were indexed, in which case MySQL would be able to read just the row that corresponds to the first index entry).